# I need Reqular Expression for t#0-9s in c# windows application

Tags: c#

Hi I want to validate this input `(t#0-9s)` with regular expression with `regex` in **C# .net** please tell me how to do that ?

**Additional Information:**

My input string should be start with `t#` and after that I have 1 or even more than 1 digit numbers and also it should be end with `'s'` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^(t#\d+s)$
```

Funnily this answer was too small and requires this text to pad it out.